# Streaming video from a webcam with JMF causes Windows 7 to switch to the basic theme

Tags: java, windows-7, webcam, jmf

My Java program that opens up a webcam stream and streams the captured video to a Swing component works, but when I launch it, it causes Windows to switch to the Basic theme. This is an excerpt from my code:

```
String str1 = "vfw:Logitech USB Video Camera:0";
String str2 = "vfw:Microsoft WDM Image Capture (Win32):0";

captureDeviceInfo = CaptureDeviceManager.getDevice(str2);
Format[] formats = captureDeviceInfo.getFormats();
for (Format format : formats) {
    System.out.println(format);
}
mediaLocator = captureDeviceInfo.getLocator();
try {
    player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(mediaLocator);
    player.start();
    Component comp;

    if ((comp = player.getVisualComponent()) != null) {
        playerPanel.add(comp);
        add(playerPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    }
```

If I comment out the line where the I add comp to playerPanel, it doesn't switch to the basic theme, so I assume that's where it goes wrong. From what I understand JMF is not maintained anymore and probably isn't fully compatible with Windows 7 Aero Theme. But still, is there a way to fix this? Why does it switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so, the answer to this one was to install the webcam drivers. I'm using a Logitech QuickCam Pro 9000, so I just downloaded the driver from Logitech's website. Apparently if you use the generic webcam driver that Windows provides you can get the behavior I described earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that it only happens when you add the component to the player panel (so when the video is visible), I think it might be related to an issue I once had with Media Player Classic.

From http://www.codecguide.com/faq_mpc.htm:

> Q: Aero gets disabled and my desktop turns to basic mode when playing
> a file in MPC
>
> A: This can happen if you selected the wrong video
> renderer in MPC options. Aero is not compatible with the Overlay
> Mixer. [...]

Probably the player component uses this Overlay Mixer to display the video. Try to find out if you can change it.

Comment: Okay, so I've tried this code on another computer and it works without having to switch to the basic theme. Could this have something to do with display drivers?

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, add the following in your constructor:

Manager.setHint(Manager.LIGHTWEIGHT_RENDERER, Boolean.TRUE);

Your problem is simply due to the fact that Swing is lightweight and the default rendering targets heavyweight components.